# How to access SharePoint files from a remote windows machine?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, remote-access

I have a few files in certain **SharePoint** folders that I would like to access from a **Windows (Virtual Machine) remote machine**. As a test, I copied the "link" of a SharePoint Excel file and used it in the WindowsVM browser and I connected successfully and opened the file.

I also tried to map a SharePoint folder's "link" within WindowsVM Folder Explorer/Network but I am getting the below error msg

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some surfing and several tests I found the solution that worked for me. I followed the PowerShell scripts on this link:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/map-network-drive-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html

and specifically the code below

[image]

After running the above code, modified to my SharePoint path, I mapped it to letter S

[image]

From this point and onwards, I am able to use the "S" drive in my batch scripts.
I hope this helps others who are facing the same issue with me :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to map a SharePoint site as a network drive (this uses WebDAV) please make sure:

1. The SharePoint site url is added to trusted sites list in Internet Option -> Security -> Trusted sites.
2. Use Internet Explorer to navigate to the SharePoint site and sign-in using your credentials and leave the browser open (this should not be required but it helps somehow)

Now try to map the site as a network drive.

If the above does not resolve the issue (and assuming you are running Windows 10) you can additionally navigate to Settings -> Accounts -> Add a work or school account.

Edit:

If you only have Edge browser (no IE) - you'll need to open the SharePoint site in IE compatibility mode on Edge and login-in (SharePoint looks ugly in this mode). Once this is done continue to map the drive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had already added the URL to my trusted sites and still, even after I keep the Edge (no internet explorer) open on the specific URL I am trying to map, I get the same error msg.

Comment: See my updates answer about using Edge

Comment: I just tried your workaround and I got an error saying "Sorry something went wrong. Can't load the application on this page..." etc. Anything else you think I can try?